# Analytic continuation of integral representation as Cauchy principal value

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-continuation, cauchy-principal-value

Suppose I have the following formula,
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{P}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,q) dx = F(q),
\end{equation}
for all $q\in\mathbb{R}$, where P stands for the Cauchy principal value.

If $F(q)$ is analytic for all $q\in\mathbb{C}$, and if $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,q) dx$ exists for all $q$ with $\Im[q]\not=0$, then does the formula,
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,q) dx = F(q),
\end{equation}
hold for all $q\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $\Im[q]\not=0$?

If I need to be more specific, I have the following type of integrand in my mind:
\begin{equation}
f(x,q) = \frac{g(x)}{x-q},
\end{equation}
where $g(x)$ is analytic for all $x\in \mathbb{C}$.

In other words, is it justified to analytically continue an integral representation of a function if the integral is originally given as the Cauchy principal value?

Comment: do you have a concrete example of $f$ in mind, or some context where this comes from?